# emacsclient not opening correctly in GUI mode

Tags: emacsclient

I installed emacs with homebrew and cask:

`brew cask install emacs`

It installed emacs 25.1.1.

I then linked the plist file to start emacs as a daemon on start up with:

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.emacs.plist`

I added the following exports:

```
export ALTERNATE_EDITOR=""
export EDITOR="emacsclient -t"terminal
export VISUAL="emacsclient -c -a emacs"
```

I have the following aliases:

```
alias em="emacsclient -t"
alias emax="emacsclient -c -a emacs"
```

The first one will open emacs in the terminal window and works fine but the second alias which I thought would open the GUI.

It does open the Gui but the terminal window is holding onto the process until I close the Guid down at which point it kills the emacs process and the daemon.

It displays the following text:

> Waiting for Emacs...

How can I open the GUI in a new process and shut it down without killing the daemon?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-n` to switches when invoking `emacsclient`. That's the thing you're looking for.

Comment: I mean the desktop app which I have the following alias for:

ema='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app $1'.  Is it possible to open this with emacs client?

Comment: Just point it to `emacsclient` and add `-n` to switches.